# Добавить префикс цены только для карточек товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
function iconic_format_price_range( $price, $from, $to ) {
    $prefix = __('[:de]Ab [:en]From [:ru]От [:]');
        return sprintf( '%s: %s', __(  $prefix, 'iconic' ), wc_price( $from ) );
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'iconic_format_price_range', 10, 3 );
```

С помощью данного кода добавляю префикс для цены. Но мне нужно, чтобы префикс добавлялса только для цены карточек товара. То есть если зайти на страницу товара, цена должна быть без префикса. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте is_product() для этого:

```
function iconic_format_price_range( $price, $from, $to ) {
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
    $prefix = __('[:de]Ab [:en]From [:ru]От [:]');
        $price = sprintf( '%s: %s', __(  $prefix, 'iconic' ), wc_price( $from ) );
    }

    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'iconic_format_price_range', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: это работает, но цена пропала на странице товара

Comment: Сформулируйте нормально где она должна быть) Я как вас понял - так и написал

Comment: Префикс должен быть на карточке товара (например в категории), но его не должно быть на странице товара)

Comment: Например категория - назовите нормально, на архивных страницах, страницах категорий или еще как-то) Карточка товара - это сингл-пейдж = страница товара)

Comment: Оу, сорри, я забыл как фильтрами пользоваться просто :D Поправил код